# Doing the opposite of dropna in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure this is easy to do but I cant seem to find an answer on stack overflow. I have the following dataframe.

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10,1], ['nick', 15,np.nan], ['juli', 14,1], ['mick', 15,np.nan], ['james', 18,1], ['nathan', 15,np.nan], ['jason', 17,1]
       , ['ted', 14,np.nan], ['ben',16 ,1], ['dom', 22,1]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age','Excuse']) 
print(df)

    Name  Age  Excuse
0     tom   10     1.0
1    nick   15     NaN
2    juli   14     1.0
3    mick   15     NaN
4   james   18     1.0
5  nathan   15     NaN
6   jason   17     1.0
7     ted   14     NaN
8     ben   16     1.0
9     dom   22     1.0
```

and I am hoping to delete all rows which have an `excuse` so that i get:

```
   Name  Age  Excuse

1    nick   15     NaN
3    mick   15     NaN
5  nathan   15     NaN
7     ted   14     NaN
```

Any ideas? is there a function for the opposite of `df = df.dropna(subset=['Excuse'])`? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try

```
df[df.Excuse.isna()]
```

[image]